# Using INTERVAL in PostgreSQL to add hours date/time

Tags: php, html, database, postgresql, datetime

Here is the code in PostgreSQL I am trying to run:

```
select DATE_ADD(whenbooked,INTERVAL 4 HOUR) from booking WHERE id = 12310;
```

OR I try to run this code:

```
select DATE_ADD('2010-11-19 01:11:22',INTERVAL 4 HOUR)
```

Both codes access date/time stored in the same manner:

> 2010-11-19 01:11:22

PostgreSQL error code is this:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "4"

it is referring to the '4' in the line 'INTERVAL 4 HOUR'.

I can't figure out what the issue is.

I need to compare a time/stamp (written in exactly the same format as above) with the stored time/date PLUS 4 hours.
So the desired end result is to return: `'2010-11-19 05:11:22'`.

If this can be done in PHP or directly in SQL?

Comment: Can you show it with your php code ? I guess there must be some quote issues over there.

Comment: `select DATE_ADD('2010-11-19 01:11:22',INTERVAL 4 HOUR)` works for me ...

Comment: `select DATE_ADD('2010-11-19 01:11:22',INTERVAL 4 HOUR)` works for me too

Comment: I am just typing these codes into PgAdmin. It runs the sql codes directly................I got that from the php website. I suppose there is no reason why it shouldn't work. In that case, what could be the possible reasons it doesn't work for me ?

Comment: Which version of mysql you use?

Comment: edit the question with php code as there is no problem with the query which you are using...

Comment: Working : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/37923

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment

> I am just typing these codes into **PgAdmin.**

It looks like you're actually using PostgreSQL not MySQL.

You can view your existing code running on PostgreSQL in action on PostgreSQL [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2069) which gives the same error as you get above.

To correctly work with dates in PostgreSQL, you can view a list of date functions on the PostgreSQL [documentation site here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

What you're trying to do is this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2010-11-19 01:11:22' + INTERVAL '4 HOURS';
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a method that works for me in PHP:

```
$desiredEndTime = strtotime("2010-11-19 01:11:22 + 10 hours");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $desiredendtime);
```

Looks like it converts the date/time into a weird-looking integer. And then on the second line it converts it back into my desired format. Now I can just insert that back into SQL.

Thanks!

Comment: I have added an answer which explains why it wasn't working in pure SQL for you including a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it simply to timestamp with "strtotime" method and then you can do whatever you like with that